# C++ Library to Convert HTML to PDF?

Tags: c++, html, pdf

I am looking for a C/C++ library to convert HTML (Actually XHTML + CSS) documents to PDF.

It is for commercial use and source would be nice but not essential.

Anybody have any recommendations or experience doing this?

UPDATE: To clarify, I am targeting the Windows platform only. I am developing with Borland C++ Builder 2006, but the library does not have to be a VCL component.

Many thanks in advance.

Steve.

Comment: Which platform are you talking about? There are plenty of tools on Unix/Linux, but can be tricky on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to bump this, I have evaluated both [VisPDF](http://www.vispdf.com/) and [PDFDoc Scout](http://bytescout.com/pdfdocscout.html) and will probably go with PDFDoc Scout as it can format HTML input.

Thanks for everybody else's input.

Answer (score 4):

To do that I have successfully used wkhtmltopdf.
Uses webkit and can be called from command line or as a static library. It's great and simply to use.

[wkhtmltopdf website](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

OpensSource (LGPL) and free!

Hope it can help

Comment: This is the best answer by far. wkHTMLtoPDF is much more mature than VisPDF or PDFDoc. The accepted answer doesn't even use C++ but C#..  note: wkHTMLtoPDF link is now at http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Answer (score 1):

Wouuld CLI applications do? If memory fails me not, GNU Ghostscript had utilities **html2ps** and **ps2pdf**. Source should be available too.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably overkill, but [WebKit](http://webkit.org) for rendering, with [Cairo](http://cairographics.org) for the backend could do it.    WebKit is a pretty big library, though.

If you are looking for something pre-made, I found [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) after some quick searching.  It uses WebKit and Qt for rendering, which is and even larger combination of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [HotPDF library](http://www.loslab.com/HotPDF.html), it is easy to use and good enough.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

[CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) is a free PDF writer that works as a virtual printer.  I guess you could use this in conjunction with anything that could render your HTML.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at PrinceXML.

It's definately the best HTML/CSS to PDF converter out there, although it's not free (But hey, your programming is not free either, so if it saves you 10 hours of work, you're home free.)

Oh yeah, did i mention that this is the first (and probably only) HTML2PDF solution that does full [ACID2](http://princexml.com/samples/acid2/acid2.pdf)!?!?!

http://princexml.com/samples/