# Convert PHP HTML contents to DOC/PDF with remote images and stylesheets

Tags: php, html, css, doc

I'm looking for a hassle-free script that can convert an HTML file to Microsoft Word or PDF format. My download script works already, but when I tried to open the downloaded document in MS Word the images are labeled X, and it prompted for missing files.

Can you suggest any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [PrinceXML.](http://princexml.com)

It's definitely the best HTML/CSS to PDF converter out there, although it's not free (But hey, your programming is not free either, so if it saves you 10 hours of work, you're home free.)

Oh yeah, did I mention that this is the first (and probably only) HTML2PDF solution that does full [ACID2!](http://princexml.com/samples/acid2/acid2.pdf)?

http://princexml.com/samples/

*This answer copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427927/c-library-to-convert-html-to-pdf/434894#434894); originally written by user SchizoDuckie*